# Reference book for Galois extension

Tags: reference-request, galois-theory, field-extensions

I need a reference for field extension and Galois extension (like an introduction) please.

Thank you.

Comment: What about Serge Lang, Algebra, 1th Ed. (1965), ch. 7 & 8?

Comment: A more elementary introduction is E. Artin, Galois theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many references for such topics. As @DieterKadelka suggested, the book by Lang is a really good reference. You may also be interested in the following ones:

*Bastida, J. R. (1984). Field Extensions and Galois Theory. Cambridge University Press*

*Edwards, Harold M. (1984). Galois Theory. Graduate Texts in Mathematics. 101. New York: Springer-Verlag*

*Hungerford, T. (2012). Abstract Algebra: An introduction. 3rd ed.*

*Girardi, M; Israel, G. (1976). Teoria dei campi. Feltrinelli Editore Milano*

Comment: In addition to the references indicated above, I would suggest a very good textbook that, however, is in Italian: Teoria dei campi, by Mario Girardi and Giorgio Israel, Feltrinelli editore Milano

Comment: Thanks. I have added it to the above list.